# Trying to check if a value is undefined to control setting of ng-checked

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-checked

I have a problem setting `ng-checked` to true for checkboxes based on whether a value is undefined or not. For example in the following code..

```
<input class="custom-checkbox form-control" id="{{ point.pointId }}-{{ value }}"
  type="checkbox" 
  ng-true-value="'{{ value }}'" 
  ng-model="item.sections[inspectionSection.sectionShortName[point.pointId].value">
```

I am trying to set `ng-checked` by checking if `value`, which can be set to one of several values, is defined.

For example something like:

```
ng-checked={{ if(value !== undefined) }}
```

I can't seem to get it working. Anything I try in `ng-checked` either checks all the checkboxes or none. Any help much appreciated!

Comment: any news about this question?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using a function in this case.

```
ng-checked="isNotUndefined(value)"

// in the controller
isUndefined (value) {
   return value !== undefined
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can accomplish this by using the ternary operator:

```
ng-checked="value !== undefined ? true : false"
```

Comment: Understood, but thought I'd add it as it's an alternative solution to the one you posted.